# How to determine if a message is read in Slack using simple-slack-api

Tags: java, slack, slack-api

I'm using the [simple-slack.api](https://github.com/Ullink/simple-slack-api) to send and receive Slack messages.
Is there a way to decide if a message was read?

I found that I can get the history of a channel, but the `SlackMessagePosted` does not contain any field if the message was read or not (the `MessageSubType` does not include it)

Comment: No, Slack API does not provide such information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible.

The Slack API (e.g. [`channels.history`](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.history) or [`conversations.history`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history)) does not provide any information about which messages are unread and by whom.

The only thing you get is the total number of unread messages for your current user as defined by the token you are using (by setting the parameter `unreads` to true), but I guess that is not what you are looking for.